# Lubuntu 20.04- How do I disable the virtual keyboard on login screen?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, gedit

I'm unable to find any settings to disable it.
I did find one post on it but
I get an error when I try to follow the post.

I attempted this:
sudo gedit /etc/sddm.conf

I got this:
sudo: gedit: command not found

It goes on to say:

Then in the General section add:
InputMethod=

Save and restart.

Firstly how do I get the gedit command to work?
and will this fix the problem?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I got gedit working thanks but
I only have 2 lines of text come up:

1. [Autologin]
2. Session=Lubuntu

So I don't know what to do with this:
Then in the General section add:
InputMethod=
do I just type that below the first 2 lines and save it
or am I missing something??

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, To install gedit `sudo apt install gedit` Lubuntu doesn't have `gedit` on default packages, `vi` or `nano` is a terminal text editor. `Leafpad` for GUI. you can change `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` if you install your favorite GUI text editor already.

Comment: `leafpad`, I think, went away with Lubuntu 18.04. Don't know what the text editor is in later versions.

Comment: it is featherpad.

Comment: The Lubuntu manual uses `nano` in the sddm configuration section by example (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.9/sddm_configuration.html?highlight=sddm) though `featherpad` is the default LXQt editor as @nobody said, and `vim` is installed by default too (for those familiar with vi/vim)

Comment: Thanks, Sadaharu for the help with gedit that worked great, I've edited my question seeking advice on the second part, any help with it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question, yes essentially you would just add it to the file and it should look like this:

```
[General]
InputMethod=
```

For reference, a similar question has been asked on the Lubuntu forum as well. https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/removing-keyboard-on-boot/1932/7

Comment: Thank you all very much for your time and help. 